# How to add Equality constraint in Cplex using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, constraints, equality, cplex

I am implementing a scheduling model in Cplex using Matlab. The model is a flow shop model, and is as follows:

[Flow shop model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQiKE.png)

where `z_{j,i}` are binary and `s_{r,i}` are integers. Also, `p_{r,j}` are problem data. I am trying to write the first two constraints, that are in the form of equality, and using `cplex.addRows`. But I don't know how to specify that these constraints are in the form of equality, rather than less than or equal.

As far as I know, `cplex.addRows(lhs,A,rhs,rowname)` does not have the part `sense` to specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to have the same lhs and rhs?

In the example lpex3.m you may see

```
%   minimize  c*x
%   subject to  Hx = d
%               Ax = b
%               l <= x <= u
```

and in the model

```
cplex.addRows(b, A, b);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. That should be the correct way. I n the same post I will share the other issues I face, as well as the built code at the end, to be a complete guide for future references.